# How to pass Viewdata value to masterpage in Razor MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

I use Directoryservices for login in My page. I need to pass the username to my masterpage to display the username in all the pages.

I got the username and stored it in a ViewData. How to pass the viewdata value in masterpage.
 
My code :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModels model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string DisplayUserName = string.Empty;
            string LoginUser = model.Userid;
            string LoginPassword = model.Password;    
            string  name = model.UserName
            if (ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(LoginUser, LoginPassword, out DisplayUserName) == true)
            {
                model.UserName = DisplayUserName;
                ViewData["UserName"] = "Welcome" + DisplayUserName;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MPP", new { UserID = LoginUser });
            }          
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid Username or Password");
            }               
        }
        return View();          
    }
```

In Layout page :

```
   @{  @ViewData["UserName"]   }
```

I tried the following way to display the Username. But it throws nullexception.
EDIT :

```
@foreach (var m in IEnumerable<SampleECommerce.Models.LoginModels>)ViewData["UserName"])
{ 
    @m.UserName
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some misunderstandings, like if you set `ViewData["UserName"]` to a string value you get a `IEnumerable<SampleECommerce.Models.LoginModels>`.  Here is another solution:

Put this to layout page:

```
<span>@{Html.RenderAction("actionname", "controllername");}</span>
```

And in related action:

```
 public ActionResult actionname() {
        string result = getusername();
        return Content(result);
    }


[NoneAction]
private string getusername(){
    return (Membership.GetUser()!= null) ? Membership.GetUser().UserName : "Guest";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the extra @, i.e.

```
   @{  ViewData["UserName"]   }
```

Comment: Although it's not needed, it will still work with the extra @

Answer (score 0):

Firs you need to change your syntax to:

```
@(ViewData["UserName"])
```

That's probably the best (*of a bad bunch*).  Realistically you should be looking to push your user into the `User` property of your pages via the `User` property of your controllers (typically in an authorization attribute where, perhaps, you read a cookie) - that way you don't rely on type-unsafe `ViewData` and magic strings for something that you're going to be using on ***every page***.

But anyway... if the view is rendering because of the last `return View();` line then what you're trying to do will work if you change your syntax as I've shown.

If not, and it's when you do `return RedirectToAction("Index", "MPP", new { UserID = LoginUser });` then you need to push the UserName into `TempData` and then read it back at the start of the `Index` action on your `MPP` controller:

So:

```
TempData["UserName"] = "Welcome " + DisplayUserName;
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MPP", new { UserID = LoginUser });
```

And then at the start of your `Index` method you need to pull the value back out of `TempData`:

```
public class MPPController {
  public ActionResult Index(){
    ViewData["UserName"] = TempData["UserName"];
  }
}
```

Why do you have to do this?  Because `RedirectToAction` doesn't render a page - it tells the client to make a different request to a new Url - thus any `ViewData` or model or whatever is thrown away as far as the server is concerned.  `TempData` is there to provide temporary storage between ***two successive requests only*** - thus it works well for the `RedirectToAction` scenario.

Like I say though - this really is a poor way to persist your user information from controller to view and you should seriously rethink it as a matter of urgency.

Answer (score 0):

in layout page:

```
<span>@{Html.RenderAction("actionname", "controllername");}</span>
```

in controller store a session variable

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModels model)
{
      Session["username"] = model.UserName;
     //remaining code
}
```

add  one  more function

```
public ActionResult actionname() {

    return Content(Session["username"]);
}
```

so here we dont need additional functions.